# Is a covariance matrix defined through a Gaussian covariance function always positive-definite?

Tags: machine-learning, covariance-matrix, gaussian-process

When using Gaussian processes, the covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is often defined via a covariance function $K$ as follows
$$
\mathbf{\Sigma}_{ij} = K(\underline{x}_i, \underline{x}_j)
$$
where $\underline{x}_i, \underline{x}_j$ are coordinates of two points in some space of interest, and belong to some finite set of $n$ such points, resulting in a $n \times n$ covariance matrix.

Is it known whether the Gaussian (or 'squared exponential') covariance function
$$
K(\underline{x}_i, \underline{x}_j) = a^2 \exp{\left(-\frac{(\underline{x}_i - \underline{x}_j)^{\top}(\underline{x}_i - \underline{x}_j)}{2l^2}\right)}
$$
will *always* produce a positive-definite $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ for any chosen set of points and values of $a, l$?

Thanks!

Comment: Positive-definite, No; Nonnegative defiinite (sometimes called positive semidefinite) Yes.

Comment: @DilipSarwate oh interesting - I don't suppose you know a source for a proof of that? Thanks

Comment: It's got nothing to do with Gaussian random variables or processes _per se._.  **All** covariance matrices (no matter what the (finite-variance) random variables are) _must_ be positive semi-definite. See [this answer of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/69117/6633) to see why this must be so.