# Is every correlation matrix positive semi-definite?

Tags: covariance-matrix, linear-algebra, correlation-matrix

I am generating correlation matrix by some new algorithm. Generated matrix is non positive semi-definite matrix.

I'm getting a few negative eigenvalues. The rest of eigenvalues are quite equal to the ideal matrix.

Can I use that non positive semi-definite matrix? If not, why?

If my estimated correlation matrix has all positive but complex value and imaginary terms are close to zero then is it possible?

Comment: One of a number of very similar questions on CV http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/69114/3277.

Comment: it cannot be correct, so the algorithm has some issues.

Comment: Near-duplicates: [Is every correlation matrix positive definite?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182875/is-every-correlation-matrix-positive-definite) which has more focus on the definite versus semi-definite angle, and [Is every covariance matrix positive definite?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56832/is-every-covariance-matrix-positive-definite) which is relevant because a covariance is essentially a rescaled correlation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is every covariance matrix positive definite?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56832/is-every-covariance-matrix-positive-definite)

Answer (score 11):

A correlation matrix is really the covariance matrix of a bunch of variables which have been rescaled to have variance one.

[But every population covariance matrix is positive semi-definite](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56832/is-every-covariance-matrix-positive-definite), and if we rule out weird cases (such as with missing data, or "[numerical fuzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_error)" turning a small eigenvalue to a negative one), so is every sample covariance matrix.

So if a matrix is supposed to be a correlation matrix, it should be positive semi-definite.

Note that the *semi*-definite is important here. In the bivariate case, take your two variables to be perfectly positively correlated and then the correlation matrix is $\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 1& 1}$ which has eigenvalues of $2$ and $0$: the zero eigenvalue means it is *not* positive definite.

Answer (score 6):

Negative eigenvalues would imply that by the diagonalizing transformation the random vector would have negative variance in some components. Negative variances do never exist.

Answer (score 1):

A correlation matrix is positive semi-definite, period.  Numerics, however, might refuse to acknowledge that mathematical fact depending on how you arrive at the numeric representation of the correlation matrix.

The solution is to choose a representation of your matrix that cannot fail to be positive semi-definite by representing the matrix in a suitable decomposed form.  I am not up to scratch, but there are things like LUD decompositions or square root forms that essentially are unable to represent anything but truly positive semi-definite matrices and which you can usually update incrementally similarly to how you would update the full matrix, possibly even easier.