# What does it mean to say that a covariance matrix is ​a positive definite matrix?

Tags: terminology, covariance-matrix, definition

I'm doing a work on covariance matrix and this question came to me that was not very clear.

Comment: Related questions: [Is every covariance matrix positive definite?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/56832/22228) considers the broader case of covariance matrices, of which correlation matrices are a special case; also [Is every correlation matrix positive semi-definite?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/125412/22228) and [Is every correlation matrix positive definite?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/182875/22228)

Comment: Also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69114/why-does-correlation-matrix-need-to-be-positive-semi-definite-and-what-does-it-m

Answer (score 1):

An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is said to be positive definite if $\mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x}>0 \>\forall \> \mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{0} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  The term "positive definite" just refers to a subclass of matrices.

Comment: usually also taken to be symmetric

Comment: If you replace $\gt$ by $\ge$ then you have the definition of *positive semidefinite*