# Why is covariance matrix not positive-definite when number of observations is less than number of dimensions?

Tags: factor-analysis, covariance-matrix

I have a data matrix $X$ of size $n\times p$ with $n < p$, where $n$ is the number of observations and $p$ is the number of dimensions.

**My question is: why $n < p$ results in not a positive-definite covariance matrix?**

(By the way I want to use this data in a Factor Analysis model. Do you have any idea about Matlab code implementing a standard Factor Analysis for this kind of data when $n < p$?)

Comment: You cannot do factor analysis (most algorithms and implementations won't allow) on a singular correlation matrix (and when n<p, it is but [singular](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/70899/3277)) as well as negative-definite matrix (which could appear sometimes with pairwise deletion of missng values).

Comment: @ttnphns; Is there any solution to the problem or simply I have to forget factor analysis?

Comment: This is a theoretical problem (see [Pt 6](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/198684/3277)). Due to relatively low `n` correlations cannot enough differentiate from one another and do not allow the factor model to play in full accordingly. So forget FA. It is good to have n>p at least 3-5 times, practically.

Comment: Then in my case which method of dimension reduction would you suggest? And can you also propose a standard matlab code for that method?

Comment: +1 but your second question (about the Matlab code) is off-topic here.

Comment: I wouldn't know why you couldn't at least look via principal components and rotations on your data to see patterns or to reduce to a smaller number of components? (Of course a true factor analytic model expects itemspecific variance which you cannot model with your data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This result is a direct, simple consequence of the fact that [the rank of the $p\times p$ matrix $X^\prime X$ cannot be any greater than the smaller of $n$ and $p$,](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60622/why-is-a-sample-covariance-matrix-singular-when-sample-size-is-less-than-number/180360#180360) which is strictly less than $p$ in this case.  That makes the $p\times p$ matrix $X^\prime X$ singular, which is equivalent to the existence of a nonzero $x$ for which $X^\prime X x = 0$.  Consequently $$x^\prime X^\prime X x = x 0 = 0$$ demonstrates that $X^\prime X$ is indefinite.

Although I referenced $X$ in this argument, the column-centered version of $X$ that is used in computing the covariance matrix also has dimensions $n\times p$, so the same conclusions apply to it.

---

#### Definitions

The *rank* of a matrix $X$ is the dimension of its image, defined to be the set of all $Xx$ as $x$ ranges among all possible vectors.

The *column-centered* version of a matrix is obtained by subtracting the arithmetic mean of each column from the entries in that column.

The *covariance matrix* of $X$ is proportional to $Y^\prime Y$ where $Y$ is the column-centered version of $X$.  (Depending on convention, the factor of proportionality is $1/n$ or $1/(n-1)$.)

A square matrix $A$ is *singular* when it has no multiplicative inverse.  Equivalently, there is a nonzero vector $x$ for which $Ax=0$.  ($A$ has a nontrivial *kernel*.)  Equivalently, the rank of $A$ is strictly less than the dimension of its image space (equal to the number of rows of $A$).

A square matrix $A$ is *semi-definite* when all numbers of the form $x^\prime A x$ have the same sign (or are zero), regardless of what the vector $x$ might be.  According to the sign, $A$ would be called negative semi-definite or positive semi-definite.

A semi-definite square matrix $A$ is *definite* when the only vector $x$ for which $x^\prime A x = 0$ is the zero vector itself.