# If $\vec y \sim N(\vec 0,\Sigma)$, what is the distribution of $y^TAy$, when $A$ is indefinite?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, chi-squared-distribution, quadratic-form

Suppose $\vec y \sim N(\vec 0,\Sigma)$ with $\Sigma$ singular. Is the distribution of $y^TAy$ known in the case that $A$ is indefinite?

Comment: what does indefinite mean?

Comment: @Taylor http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndefiniteQuadraticForm.html

Comment: @Taylor See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/301714/919 on this site.  Marius: $y^\prime A y$ is a linear combination of $\chi^2(1)$ variates.  I believe you can unearth this answer, with details, by [searching our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normal+quadratic+chi).  The singularity of $\Sigma$ is irrelevant.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. But I already had to look. I just searched your suggest phrase, and I didn't find an answer.

Comment: Here's one at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479.  It shows how to find a sum of Gammas.  (A $\chi^2(1)$ is a multiple of a Gamma$(1/2)$ distribution.) Somewhere we have a thread about general linear combinations of Gammas, but it only cites references. Linear algebra shows that $y^\prime A y$ is distributed like a linear combination of sums of squared Normal variates and therefore is a linear combination of Gammas--those linear algebraic arguments are quoted in many threads concerning quadratic forms in Normal variables (and they're simple).

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I need the details, is it possible that you suggest a paper or textbook which derives the distribution of $y'Ay$ when $A$ is indefinite? I looked at Mathai, Provost: Quadratic Forms in Random Variables. From what I can tell, it does not contain the answer.

Comment: This is called the [generalized chisquare distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution) or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/338989/generalized-chi-squared-distribution-pdf/339984#339984.  Look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442472/sum-of-squares-of-dependent-gaussian-random-variables/442916#442916) and as an exercise, extend the arguments to singular covariance matrix using generalized inverses